# Can I plug an Ethernet Cable from my PS3 to a MacBook Pro, and share its Internet?

Tags: macos, ps3, tethering, connection-sharing

The WiFi adapter on my PS3 is really bad. I'm with a Mac here,

Is it possible to plug an Ethernet cable from the PS3 to the Mac, and share the internet connection?

So, I would "fool" the PS3, thinking it's a normal ethernet connection, but in fact is going to use the WiFi from the Mac.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have found a **great tutorial**, exactly what I needed!

http://www.mobile-broadband-reviews.com/sharing-mobile-broadband-ps3.html#mac

I needed to do what was at the `What To Do If It Doesn’t Work` section though: (a little transcription)

> Configure your mac ethernet config selecting ‘Using DHCP with
>   manual address’. Set the IP Address to 10.0.0.1.   Going through the
>   same process, instead of setting everything on the PS3 to automatic,
>   you’ll to change a couple things:
>
> For IP Address Setting, DHCP host name & DNS Settings respectively,
>   you’ll need to choose “Manual”, “Set” & “Manual”. The settings you
>   need should match the following:
>
> IP Settings: Manual
>
> IP Address: 10.0.0.2
>
> Subnet Mask: 255.255.0.0
>
> Gateway: 10.0.0.1
>
> DNS Settings: Manual
>
> Primary DNS Server: 192.168.2.1
>
> Secondary DNS Server: 192.168.2.1

Comment: Please include the relevant parts **here** and don't point somewhere else.

Comment: @slhck: The relevant parts is the whole article. I don't want to just copy and paste what is in that link.

Comment: You won't believe how many sites like these go offline within a few months. Super User should be a canonical resource of information. It would be great to include the at least the *essentials* (copy/paste is a no-go anyway!). Steps 1-8 can be easily condensed, Steps 9-22 as well. Remember that you should *always quote the most relevant part of an important link, in case the target site is unreachable or goes permanently offline* [according to the FAQ](http://superuser.com/questions/how-to-answer).

Comment: @slhck: Ok. I don't have time right now, but will condense here what worked in my scenario, and mark my answer as accepted.

Answer (score 2):

You are able to. In the Settings on the Macbook Pro, go to the Sharing and enable Internet Sharing. You'll need to select your wireless card as the shared device.

I thought that the PS3 had built in WiFi? (don't own one so I don't know). If you do not have a wireless router and only have the Cable Modem (or similar) you can do the opposite of above. Still go to the Internet Sharing, but you'll want to select your ethernet as the shared device.

Comment: The ps3 has builtin wi-fi. But it's terrible.